# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 on MacOS / nasm

Tags: macos, assembly, x86, nasm

I am new to assembly programming so I apologize in advance.

I have issues linking my first `Hello world` assembly program in `MacOS` and `nasm`.

```
section .data
        text db "Hello World",10

section .text
        global _start

_start:
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, text
        mov rdx, 14
        syscall

        mov rax, 60
        mov rdi, 0
        syscall
```

I am using a `MacOS 10.13.6` so I compiled it with `nasm`as follows without erroes:

```
nasm -f macho64 -o test.o test.asm
```

However when I link with `ld`:

```
ld -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.13 test.o -o test
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I have tested it on my `linux` distro and it works fine, so I am not sure what is different with `MacOS` as both my computers are `x86_64`.

Comment: Assembly is not portable between operating systems.  You can make this assemble by decorating each symbol with an underscore in the beginning (i.e. `_main` instead of `main`) but it still won't work because macOS has different system calls than Linux.  Also, the sections might be called differently, not sure though.

Comment: Thanks. I removed the underscore and I got it compiling... It indeed did not like it apparently

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70618270/8258079

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to compile program：CMach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70617633/unable-to-compile-program-cmach-o-64-bit-format-does-not-support-32-bit-absolute)

Comment: Yes indeed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

On macOS be sure to define your `_main` entry point, using underscores as follows:

```
global  _main
```

```
_main:
```

Furthermore, that code using Linux system-call numbers won't work on macOS until that and some other issues are worked out: see *[Unable to compile program：CMach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70617633/unable-to-compile-program-cmach-o-64-bit-format-does-not-support-32-bit-absolute/70618270#70618270)*

Answer (score 2):

Also, if your source code uses `_start` entry point, you can use the `-e _start` command line option with `ld` to tell it to use `_start` rather than `_main`.

I generally modify the source to use `_main`, but this is an alternate solution.