# nasm MacOS Ventura Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_main"

Tags: macos, nasm

I am trying to write a hello world program using NASM version `2.16.01` on macOS Ventura (`13.4`). I am on a 2019 core i7 Mac.

My code `helloworld.asm`:

```
global _main

SECTION .data
msg     db      'Hello World!', 0x0A ; assign msg variable
 
SECTION .text
 
_main:
 
    mov     rdx, 13          ; number of bytes to write - one for each letter plus LF char.
    lea     rsi, [rel msg]   ; move the memory address of our message string into rsi
    mov     rdi, 1           ; write to the STDOUT file
    mov     rax, 0x2000004   ; invoke SYS_WRITE (kernel opcode 4)
    syscall
    
    mov     rax, 0x2000001   ; exit
    mov     rdi, 0
    syscall
```

When I try to compile and execute it, I get the same error:

```
% ld helloworld.o -o hello -lSystem -L/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Code and terminal commands from [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70617633/unable-to-compile-program-cmach-o-64-bit-format-does-not-support-32-bit-absolute/70618270#70618270).

I have tried to use code and parameters from [this article](https://medium.com/@thisura1998/hello-world-assembly-program-on-macos-mojave-d5d65f0ce7c6). I get the same error. Also happens with `start` instead of `_main`.

It feels like these errors may be new with recent versions of MacOS (Ventura), but I can't seem to find any explanation or fix online.

May also be important to mention that I get the following warnings when I compile into an object file:

```
% nasm -f macho64 -o helloworld.o helloworld.asm
helloworld.asm:3: warning: attempt to initialize memory in BSS section: ignored [-w+other]
helloworld.asm:3: warning: section size may be negativewith address symbols [-w+other]
helloworld.asm:3: warning: attempt to initialize memory in BSS section: ignored [-w+other]
helloworld.asm:3: warning: section size may be negativewith address symbols [-w+other]
```

How do I go about compiling and executing NASM on MacOS Ventura?

Comment: How did you install `nasm` ?

Comment: `brew install nasm`